# Linux apache2 перенаправление с публичного IP на локальный

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache, ip, apache2

У меня на сервере (Amazon AWS - Ubuntu Server) есть публичный IP - допустим 11.12.13.14 .

При вводе в браузере (на сервере) - http://localhost никаких проблем нет, страница работает. Но на другом компютере в браузере http://11.12.13.14 выводит - "Не удается получить доступ к сайту". Как мне теперь перенапрвить - http://11.12.13.14 на http://localhost в apache.

Или для этого мне надо домен, тоесть нельза получить доступ к сайту только с вводом IP в адресную строку.

Объясните пожалуйста подробнее.

Comment: Если из **внешней** сети доступ по IP адресу есть, а из локальной нет, значит нужен маскарадинг на роутере. Если нигде нет, значит у IP адреса возраст не очень (меньше суток). Подробнее опишите свою конфигурацию.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Из локальной доступ етсть, а из внешней нет. И ещё 80 порт закрыт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Не забудь настроить у себя на apache https и dns-имя, ip-адрес. Т.е будем считать что у твоего apache-сервера ip address - 192.168.0.51/24.
2. Если публичным ip-адресом заправляешь ты, то настраивай у себя на сервере, где прикручен этот публичный адрес следующее:

   iptables -A PREROUTING -d 11.12.13.14/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.51

Это перенаправит трафик на твой локальный сервер.
 3. Если не ты управляешь настройками внешнего адреса, проси тех у кого он в распоряжении перенаправить трафик на твою локальную машину.

---

В принципе все просто. Всегда помни, если ты имеешь локальную сеть с адресацией(192.168.0.1/24) и у тебя есть публичный адрес, то тебе надо перенаправить трафик с внешнего ip на внутренний ip.